Differentiating 迟缓 and 延迟 in terms of cognitive delay?
When trying to translate "cognitive delay" in terms of one's neurodevelopment, I have come in terms of both 迟缓 and 延迟. However, I am having difficulties differentiating the two, if there are any differences.
My understanding:
迟缓 (slow) = 因为发育较慢而导致的延迟
slower speed (tardy) + falling behind others
Generally is an chronic issue (慢性疾病) with slowness in development in a specific nature. (i.e. intellectual disabilities)
Examples:

认知迟缓 (Cognitive Delay / Sluggishness)
语言迟缓 (Speech Delay / Sluggishness)
发育迟缓 (Developmental Delay)

延迟 (delay) =  因为外部因素而被退后
later start (postpone; time related) + falling behind others
Delay in reaching specific milestones in developmental stages. Such as in a child's progress. It can be caused by a range of other factors. (i.e. language barrier, lack of background knowledge, etc...) Itself does not necessarily indicate a disability.
Examples:

认知延迟 (Cognitive Delay)
(more accurate in contrast to the first)

语言延迟 (Speech Delay)

运动延迟 (Motor Delay)



While both sounds similar, but I hope I did not misunderstand in any.

I agree with @Tang Hong that 迟缓 means already started yet progressing slow (>0), while 延迟 means haven't started (=0). Based on my search, the term translation development delay=发育迟缓 appears more often but 青春期发育延迟 is also commonly used. In traditional Chinese context they seem to be no differences BTW.


迟缓 = slow

延迟 = delay


The difference between "slow progressing" and a "delay to start"

迟缓: Slow-progressing at slower than normal speed and therefore falling behind (although started at the same time as others)

延迟: Delayed - Started late and therefore fell behind (even progress at normal speed)


認知延遲 = "cognitive delay" - your brain does not start prossessing the signal as soon as normal people would
認知迟缓 = "cognitive delay" your brain does not prossess the signal as fast as  normal people would
Both terms mean your cognitive function is slow, just for a different reason. Strictly speaking, "cognitive delay" should be translated as "認知延遲"

Here is my understanding:
迟缓 - slow; tardy

行動迟缓 - slow in action/motion

反應迟缓 - slow in response/reaction

發育迟缓 - tardy in (growth) development


延迟 - keep putting off (til a later date/time); delay; postpone

火車起程時間延迟了一個小時 - The train boarding time is delayed for an hour.

會議必須準時開始, 不能再延迟了 - The meeting must start on time, it can't be delayed/postponed again.

父母的溺愛延迟了他的個人成長 - Parents' blind love has delayed his personal growth.



Yes, I think 延迟 can be very general. Like it has the other meaning of "time" as well
